# Using jQuery template to render JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-templates

I have been trying for days to get my head around a little bit of JSON rendering using jQuery templates with no success... I was hoping someone more intelligent than me could spot where I'm going wrong.

So my JSON data returns something similar to this:

```
[{"pk": 1, "model": "blobs.blob", "fields": {"content": "hello"}}, {"pk": 2, "model": "blobs.blob", "fields": {"content": "goodbye"}}];
```

I then try and render each item returned by JSON using jQuery templates:

```
var blob_template = '<p>${content}</p>';

$.template('blobTemplate', blob_template );

$.getJSON('/myurl/', function(data) {

    $('blobTemplate').empty();

    var blobs = data;

    $.tmpl('blobTemplate', blobs)
        .appendTo('div');
});
```

The template renders fine but without the data from ${content}. I don't get any error or undefined message, but I don't know where Im going wrong? Any help would be very much appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

Ok so to avoid using a deprecated method or additional scripts/plugins, is this a better approach instead?

```
$.getJSON('/myurl/', function(data) {
    var blobs = [];

    $.each(data, function(i, data) {
        var blob_template = '<p>' + data[i].fields.content + '</p>';

        blobs.push(blob_template);
    });

    $(notes.join('')).appendTo('div');
});
```

This seems to result in a data[i] is undefined though :(

Comment: Are you using the deprecated jQuery templating plugin or the new template functionality being developer for jQuery UI?

Comment: Please specify your `template` section

Comment: I was basing my template from these:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.tmpl/#example-1
http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js

Answer (score 0):

From my limited knowledge about the deprecated templates plugin, it's not picking up the *content* property because it's not a top level property of each object in your JSON object collection. I think your template should look like this:

```
<p>
    {{each fields}}
        ${$value}
    {{/each}}
</p>
```

Comment: You say deprecated... is there a better/newer way to construct html templates from JSON with jQuery? Keeping in mind that this is a simple example, the actual version needs to build 20 lines of HTML for each item in the JSON return :(

Comment: I say deprecated because it is not officially supported anymore, as made apparent by the notice on the page: http://api.jquery.com/category/plugins/templates/. I think the guy working on it is now working on JsViews which is basically the "new" templates: https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews. So might be worth checking that out first before you get into the templates and build a big project around them.

Answer (score 0):

Have you included https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl/master/jquery.tmpl.min.js ? (because jQuery.template is beta)

What are you doing there `$('blobTemplate').empty();`? I don't think that you have an blobTemplate tag

you replace `${content}` with `data[i].content` but your content field is in `data[i].fields.content` ...?